# Camera Intent in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera-intent

I have a problem with using the camera intent in Fragment. I have an Activity which contains fragments, and I have four fragments. In my 3rd fragment I have call the camera Intent. After take a picture, the app doesn't resume only on the 3rd fragment, but it also appear the 1st fragment. You can see the pictures and the code.

Thanks for any solutions.

Code:

```
public class CreateAttachment extends Fragment{

private RelativeLayout btnBack, btnNext;
private LinearLayout btnAttachment, btnCapture;

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_property_attachment, container, false);

    btnBack = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.attachment_btnBack);
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    });

    btnNext = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.attachment_btnNext);
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nextFragment();
        }
    });

    btnAttachment = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAttachment);
    btnAttachment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        }
    });

    btnCapture = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.btnCameraAccess);
    btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Photo is Chosen",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Photo is Captured",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
}
```

Images:
[Here is my screenshot for 1st fragment, 3rd fragment, and the issue after take a picture by Camera Intent in the 3rd fragment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuUUQ.jpg)

Comment: is the same thing happening for `btnAttachment` too?

Comment: For btnAttachment is worked fine.

Comment: try removing the line `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`

Comment: You can set Background color to white(#ffffff) to all your layouts for Fragments, It will solve this problem.

Comment: @Peter do you get the call back ( OnActivityResult )in 3rd fragment ? is toast visible after click photo?

Comment: @SuhasB yes, I get the call back in my 3rd fragment. the toast is show

Comment: @Bhargav, it still show the same issue.

Comment: @user5716019, it still show the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of your answer. Anyway I don't know exactly what the error is, but the way to fix this  is to override these two functions of the Activity on my 3rd fragment.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Work on onCreate when return into Fragment.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent,
                        CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

in OnActivityResult remove     `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {



    }
```

Comment: It might be the solution, but I don't know how to save and restore the InstanceState. So can you please share me any example?

Comment: after remove the line of code, it still show the same issue. when we try to capture the photo more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be in your code of add/replace fragment. your 1st and 3rd fragment are overlapping because you might have not hide(fragment) your fragment on replacing 1st fragment by 3rd fragment.